# Collective confidence of a function - r squared

Tags: r, regression, density-function

I have a series of plots, showing time delay against saturation ratio. For each plot I perform a third order polynomial regression to relate time delay to saturation ratio. This generates a function illustrated as the red line. As shown in Figure 1.

The regression function has a corresponding R$^2$ adjusted value, also shown in Figure 1. For comparison, a BPR function is taken from the literature and also plotted.

[image: Figure 1]

I have around 40 of these plots. Each consisting of an individual road. For each road I perform a third order polynomial regression to generate a function.

I wish to assess the collective value of this method and display the collective R$^2$ values in some way.

I have looked at using a density plot in order to do this.

Using ggplot I plotted the range of R$^2$ adjusted values, as shown in Figure 2.

[image: Figure 2]

This appears to show a significant number of functions fall between 0.4 and 0.7 R$^2$ adjusted values.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "this method" (polynomial regression? third order? using $R^2$? plotting?) and what the "collective value" might refer to?  How might the data in the plots be related to each other?